# How to restart an STM32 timer halfway with a new value?

Tags: timer, stm32

I have a timer which at each interrupt first stops itself and then set its own next delay:

```cpp
HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim);
// do stuff
__HAL_TIM_SET_PRESCALER(&htim, new_p);
__HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD(&htim, new_a);
__HAL_TIM_CLEAR_FLAG(&htim, TIM_FLAG_UPDATE);
HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim);
```

everything works well. But if I stop the timer before it overflows and interrupts, and then fill it with new values, it keeps finishing its last delay. For example, I stop it a second into a 15-second delay and fill it with values for 1 second delay, after I start it again, it takes ~13 seconds to interrupt instead of 1 second.

Comment: There is a control bit "auto reload preload" that you need to turn off.  The manual is very detailed and the timers are quite simple.  My advice is to not use the HAL and just write to the registers directly.

Answer (score 2):

New value of the prescaler, written in the `PSC` register, is loaded in the actual prescaler register only at the next update event. If you don't want to wait for next counter overflow - generate a software update event by writing the `UG` bit in `TIMx_EGR` register.

New auto-reload value is loaded in the actual auto-reload register immediately, unless "auto-reload preload" option is enabled with the `ARPE` bit in `TIMx_CR1` register. In this case the actual auto-reload register is also loaded with an update event.